# Zabbix load/cpu roll-your-own formula

Tags: zabbix

I know that newer versions of Zabbix (2.0 onward) has a simple way of determining average load per cpu via the introduction of the "percpu" parameter.  Unfortunately, I'm using 1.8.

With 2.0 I would be able to create an item with this key: `system.cpu.load[percpu,avg15]`

How do I roll-my-own calculated item using 1.8?  I have tried the following formulas (Many are desperate and improbable, I know):

`system.cpu.load[,avg15].last/system.cpu.num.last`

`Template_Linux:system.cpu.load[,avg15]/Template_Linux:system.cpu.num`

`{Template_Linux:system.cpu.load[,avg15]}/{Template_Linux:system.cpu.num}`

`{Template_Linux:system.cpu.load[,avg15].last}/{Template_Linux:system.cpu.num.last}`

`{Template_Linux:system.cpu.load[,avg15].last()}/{Template_Linux:system.cpu.num.last()}`

`{"Template_Linux:system.cpu.load[,avg15]".last()}/{"Template_Linux:system.cpu.num".last()}`

`"Template_Linux:system.cpu.load[,avg15]".last()/"Template_Linux:system.cpu.num".last()`

`"Template_Linux:system.cpu.load[,avg15].last()"/"Template_Linux:system.cpu.num.last()"`

Thanks!

Comment: Considering that Zabbix 1.8 is no longer supported, what prevents you from using a newer version? Note also that if you are using passive checks, you can use a Zabbix 2.x agent with Zabbix 1.8 server. Strictly speaking, using a newer agent with older server is not officially supported, but practically the passive check protocol of newer agents is compatible with Zabbix 1.8 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zabbix [documentation page on item configuration](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/items#calculated_items) describes the correct calculated item syntax.

In this case, the formula would be something like this:

```
last("system.cpu.load[,avg15]") / last("system.cpu.num")
```